# myPanel.Controls.Add(button); doesn´t work

Tags: c#, uwp

I created a `StackPanel` in `test.Xaml` View and in the `test.xaml.cs` file I would like to add a button programmatically:

```
//function: add buttons
private void add_Buttons()
{ 
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myStackPanel.Controls.Add(myButton);
}
```

The word `Controls` is underlined in the red and the error tells me:

> myStackPanel doesn´t have a Definition or Method of Controls

I think the method "Controls" is always there, or do I have to add it in the xaml Viewer, or elsewhere?

Comment: Please check the MSDN document before using a WinRT control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF Container Controls like `StackPanel` have [`Children`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx) *property* not `Controls`:

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myButton);
```